# Intellij sbt shell is not loading my environment variables

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, environment-variables, sbt

My sbt shell in Intellij did not have all of my environment variables in scope. This would cause the execution of my code to fail whenever a made a reference to an env var that was not available.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, you need to set your environment variables in a `~/.zshrc` file. Note, that Intellij does not load these from a `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file.

Just create a `.zshrc` file in your home directory, add an env variable like so:

```
export MY_VAR="test"
```

Then you need to *completely* restart your IDE. Now, when you start your sbt shell, those variables will be in scope.

Comment: do you use `zsh` as default shell? I'd assume that Idea will check your shell attached to your user by default.